# Giving an RxJava Observable something to emit from another method

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have a variable in a Fragment that will have its value change multiple times throughout the Fragment's life. It's triggered by UI interactions, so I thought it might be a good idea to use an Observable to hold it, rather than make all of the to-be-updated views as fields and do my UI changes from a setter.

The value has to be updated through another method (basically a setter that should call `onNext()` on the subscriber), not through the Observable itself. Is there a way to do that with RxJava's design?

In other words, I'm looking to have an Observable field, and give it new values to emit (calling `onNext()` on its subscribers) from another method in the class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`RxJava` has [`Subjects`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject) for this purpose. For example:

```
private final PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();

public Observable<String> getUiElementAsObservable() {
    return subject;
}

public void updateUiElementValue(final String value) {
    subject.onNext(value);
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I need! Will report back.

Comment: @D_Steve595 probably [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html) suits more in your case

Comment: That looks perfect, as I'll sometimes need to get the last emitted value. Thanks!